# How to get the current user name from login in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, authentication

I have an android form which consists of a login and the main file.
What I want to ask is how to get the current username and display it in the main xml file.

Like for example, I logged in as "james01" and when I click the log in button, I will be redirected to the next page and in the next page there is "Welcome james01"

I kinda need your help on this.

Answers are always welcome ^^

Comment: _Answers are always welcome ^^_ `Code and efforts are appreciated.`

Comment: ooppss sorry my bad. new to this so still don't know how to say thanks

Comment: May be this can help you. [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: thanks. will read that for sure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to pass the username to the 2nd activity in the intent you're using to start the activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("USERNAME", username);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in the second activity:

```
String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("USERNAME");
```

check [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

Comment: the String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("USERNAME");, should I place it with a textview or no need anymroe?

Comment: to display a message in the 2nd page, use a text view..for example textView.setText("Welcome " + username);

Comment: oh thank you. where to place the textview? in the onCreate section? or?

Comment: your second activity's layout should contain this text view, so it will be in the onCreate after setViewContent..

Comment: can I set it as toast and not as textview?

Comment: sure, Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome " + username, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

Answer (score 2):

There will be two options

- using Intent
- Using preferences

**using Intent**

pass the parameter to the next acytivity

```
Intent n = new Intent(login.this, Home.class);
n.putExtra("UserName", _username);
startActivity(n);
```

In your Home page:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras!=null)
{
    userName.setText("Welcome to "+extras.getString("UserName"));
}
```

**Using Preferences**

In Your login Page

```
preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor edit = preferences.edit();
edit.putString("pref_userName", userName);
edit.commit();
```

In your Home page

```
pref_userName = preferences.getString("pref_userName", "n/a");
userName.setText("Welcome to "+pref_userName);
```

If you have more activities and want to show username in all activities then I suggest to use `Preferences.` So this will be simple and one more thing is

If you are using preferences then don't forget to putstring `null` when you are logout from the app

Comment: in the intent section, particularly in n.putExtra("UserName", _username); is the term UserName declared or its just like a tag? and _username is my column name right? and is it ok not to put textviews anymore? simply display it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(currentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
i.putExtra("name",name.getText.toString());
StartActivity(i);
```

Get name NextActivity.class

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String name = i.getStringExtra("name");
```

and set this name to textview or toast.

Answer (score 0):

LoginAcvtivity.java

```
intent.putExtra("USERNAME",_userText.getText().toString());
```

Destinantion class.java

```
String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("USERNAME");

final TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
textViewToChange.setText(username);
```

In your xml create a < texview

```
android:id="@+id/username"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:textStyle="normal|bold|italic" />
```

This is an example from an app I am working on.